# AWS Lambda Meta-Data like EC2 Meta-Data for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata, aws-lambda

AWS EC2 Meta-Data provides the necessary information about itself from EC2 (duh!) - is there anything equivalent for lambda.

I understand the multi-tenancy and short-lived behavior of the lambda function unlike EC2 but essential info like Account ID, VPC AZ, Region would help do a lot of AWS automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an environment variable when you deploy the lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

There are already `AWS_REGION` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` variables there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables.

`event` can have fields like `requestContext.accountId`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html?shortFooter=true#eventsources-api-gateway-request

Found this out when browsing Terraform's [lambda_function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html) configuration.

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately not.  The context object is the closest thing, but the information it offers is very limited.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html

If you're invoking the lambda functions yourself or in a programmatic way, you could pass the account ID and region in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

In the context object of the Lambda, you can parse out some of the information you're looking for in the invoked_function_arn.

For example in Python: `context.split(':')[3]` will give you the region and `context.split(':')[4]` will give you the aws account id and `context.split(':')[6]` will give you the function name (which is also available in context.function_name

The invoked_function_arn looks like the following:

arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:741063561123:function:lambda_context

Once you have that information you can use aws libraries (e.g. boto3 for Python) to get the rest of the information about the lambda (such as VPC, SG)